# Is $\frac {dy} {dx} = \frac {2x} {3y}$ a homogeneous differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have a differential equation
$\dfrac {dy} {dx} = \dfrac {2x} {3y}$ 
whose solutions are
$y = \pm \sqrt {\dfrac 2 3}x $ which when I back-substitute I get $LHS=RHS$.

[From the definition on wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation#Homogeneous_linear_differential_equations)

> A linear differential equation is called homogeneous if the following condition is satisfied: If  $\phi(x)$  is a solution, so is  $c \phi(x)$, where c is an arbitrary (non-zero) constant

So taking the above definition $y = 5 \sqrt {\dfrac 2 3}x $ should work too. But if I backsubstitute this in original differential equation, I get $LHS = 5 \sqrt {\dfrac 2 3}$ and $RHS = \dfrac 1 5 \sqrt {\dfrac 2 3}$ which are not equal.

So is this still a homogeneous linear equation by definition? Am I making a mistake somewhere? Please help me understand why there are two types of homogeneity  defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation). What does it mean to be homogeneous?

Comment: This differential equation is not linear.

Comment: Do you want a homogeneous linear ODE or an ODE of homogeneous type? Yours is the latter but not the former.

Comment: @Semiclassical So how are those two different? Did you meant mine is of this type http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation#Homogeneous_type_of_first-order_differential_equations

Comment: @Tom: Yes, that's what I meant. The terminology is unfortunate, but the distinction is this: Is the solution homogeneous (i.e. it's still a solution if scaled) or is the ODE _itself_ homogeneous of some order? You've got the latter but not the former.

Comment: That makes it even more clear to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the solution should come out as $$\frac {3y^2}2=x^2+C$$or $$y^2=\frac {2x^2}3+D$$

(where $D =\frac {2C}3$ is a constant) whence $$y=\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac {2x^2}3+D\right)}$$

The constant of integration "gets in the way" here - it is added under the square root, rather than being a factor. You have ignored the constant of integration in your answer, which has misled you as to the nature of the solution.

If you had $ \dfrac {dy} {dx} =\dfrac {2y} {3x} $ that would be homogeneous. You'd get $y^3=Dx^2$ where the constant of integration comes out as a factor - so an arbitrary multiple will automatically work. So you can tell from the solution that the original equation is homogeneous. In your case clearing fractions gives you a term in $ y\dfrac {dy} {dx} $ which cannot be part of the form that your linked article says a homogeneous equation must have.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. Even with a constant D added when I multiply the solution by a constant like say "5", I don't get RHS and LHS equal on backsubstitution. So can it be called Homogeneous. My very first problem now is I am confused between this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation#Homogeneous_type_of_first-order_differential_equations and this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation#Homogeneous_linear_differential_equations

What do you mean by "nature of the solution"? Please help me understand it.

Comment: @Tom It isn't homogeneous. I am not sure why you think it is. If you had $\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {2y}{3x}$ that would be homogeneous. You'd get $y^3=Dx^2$ where the constant of integration comes out as a factor - so an arbitrary multiple will automatically work. So you can tell from the solution that the original equation is homogeneous. In your case clearing fractions gives you a term in $y\frac{dy}{dx}$ which cannot be part of the form that your linked article says a homogeneous equation must have.

Comment: thank you for the example. It cleared my thoughts a bit. So I agree and understand that it is not a "Homogeneous linear differential equation", but it still seems to me a "Homogeneous type of first-order differential equation" because of the definition here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation#Homogeneous_type_of_first-order_differential_equations.
So my question is why is homogeneity defined in two different ways? How does it help solving problem?

Comment: I've added your second comment in the answer. I need to add that to mark it correct.

Comment: @Tom Indeed according to that definition it is "homogeneous type" and the solution by alexqwx is similar to the one given in your link for equations of that type.

Comment: So homogenous has 2 uses in different contexts? And one being used only for solving problems where $\dfrac y x$ can be taken out.

Answer (score 3):

This is a first order homogeneous ODE.

$$\Large \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x}{3y}= \frac{2}{3\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}.$$

Now let $$\Large v=\frac{y}{x} \iff \underbrace{y=vx\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}}_{\text{Product rule}}.$$

Then we have $$\Large v+x \frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{2}{3v}$$ which is separable.

---

Another way of describing a (first order) homogeneous ODE is that it is of the form $$\frac{dy}{dx}=f\left(\frac{y}{x}\right),$$ where $f$ is some suitable function.

Comment: I am still stuck at this question of How a " (first order) homogeneous ODE" is different from a "Homogeneous linear differential equations". In other words I am unable to comprehend the difference between this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation#Homogeneous_type_of_first-order_differential_equations and this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation#Homogeneous_linear_differential_equations